# Methods of Singleton Class inside another Singleton Class are not executing

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, singleton

I have a singleton class A which have methods for Network Request inside another Singleton Class B.When I use the instance of A in another class C, the methods of class A are executed but the methods of Class B are not.How can I make the class B methods also get executed while calling just class A.

Here is my code:

```
class ClassA{
    
    static let shared = ClassA()

    func networkReq(){. //this method is executing
      
      ClassB.shared.doNetowrkReq() //This method is not executing
      
    }


}
```

This is how I am calling from classC

```
ClassA.shared.networkReq()
```

Comment: where is the code for classB? Why have you decided that the method is not executing?

Comment: ClassB has methods to perform Network Request .I have decided as I have debugged the code and found the methods of classB are not executing when called from classA's networkRequest()

Comment: This seems....unlikely. Can you provide some detail on class B's function.   Network requests are typically asynchronous and you have not shown any completion handlers. Please try and show *actual code*

Comment: you should
     private init() {}

Comment: Please share the code of doNetworkReq. Try putting a breakpoint inside networkReq and see if that is executed

Comment: I had a breakpoint and its not executed